# SQL CAST from XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, sqlxml

I try to CAST a XML Value e.g. 0.19 to INT and calkulate it with * 100.

But I get an error like:
Error by converting nvarchar-Value '0.19' in the INT Type.

This is the Code: (but the Row with the "CAST" is the Problem)

```
insert into BELEGP(Kennung, Belegtyp, Belegnummer, Posnummer, Postext, Zeilentyp, Menge, Steuerprozent, Eingabemenge, Editmenge, Artikelnummer, Bezeichnung, Preismenge, Einzelpreis, Gesamtpreis, Netto, Adressnr)

   SELECT  NEWID() as Kennung,
       'F' as Belegtyp,
       Myorder.j.value('OrderNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Belegnummer,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Myorder.j.value('OrderNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)')) as  Posnummer,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Myorder.j.value('OrderNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)')) as  Postext,
       'A' as Zeilentyp,
       MyItem.j.value('Quantity[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Menge,
       CAST(Cast(MyItem.j.value('TaxRate[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as nvarchar) as INT) * 100 as Steuerprozent,
       MyItem.j.value('Quantity[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Eingabemenge,
       MyItem.j.value('Quantity[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Editmenge,
       MyItem.j.value('Id[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Artikelnummer,
       MyItem.j.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Bezeichnung,
       MyItem.j.value('TotalPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Preismenge,
       MyItem.j.value('TotalPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Einzelpreis,
       MyItem.j.value('TotalPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Gesamtpreis,
       MyItem.j.value('UnityPrice[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Netto,
       Myorder.j.value('CustomerNumber[1]', 'varchar(50)') as Adressnr

   FROM (
 SELECT CAST(x AS XML)
 FROM
 OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\shop\xml\Bestellungen.xml',SINGLE_BLOB) AS k(x))
 AS k(x)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Orders/Order') AS MYorder(j)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Orders/Order/Addresses/BillingAddress') AS MYAddresses(j)
 CROSS APPLY x.nodes('Orders/Order/LineItems/LineItem') AS MYItem(j)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you could cast value 0.19 to int it would be rounded to 0. I think you have to fetch value as decimal and then do you conversion:

```
declare @Data xml = '<TaxRate>0.19</TaxRate>'
select cast(@Data.value('TaxRate[1]', 'decimal(29, 2)') * 100 as int)
```

Comment: this works:    CAST(Cast(MyItem.j.value('TaxRate[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as nvarchar) as decimal(29,2)) * 100  as Steuerprozent,

Comment: yes, but you could get value from xml right into decimal, no need to get it into varchar and then cast

Comment: Yes !!! ->            MyItem.j.value('TaxRate[1]', 'decimal(29,2)') * 100  as Steuerprozent,
it is realy better!!